# What is this .data function doing in this jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In this little snippet below I found on the web to solve one of my problems, I see .data("item.autocomplete",item) being used as a standard part of customizing the UI autocomplete widget. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is happening here. The docs are very limited for overriding the private _renderItem method. I get everything except that line. Perhaps it's the chaining that's confusing me. I get .data() as a basic cache store for an element. However, my jQuery is definitely rusty.

```
$('#name_search').autocomplete({
        source: "search/name.php"
        }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ){
            return $( "<li></li>" )
            //what is this line below?                
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.nome + "<br>" + item.cognome + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

Comment: from the docs: `The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.`.. what are you confused about?

Comment: What is "item.autocomplete"? That style of use is not in any of the method signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.data("item.autocomplete",item)
```

This sets data (the current suggestion item being rendered) on the generated `li`s in the menu that autocomplete uses. That data is later used to determine what item you're interacting with in the suggestion menu (via the `select` event or the `focus` event, for example).

If you don't set this data, autocomplete won't know that the particular `li` is associated with a particular suggestion item.

Comment: So, by chaining .data(), we are really using data() with the (element,key,value) signature? And item.autocomplete is cache that the autocomplete widget uses out of the box?

Comment: `$("<li></li>")` creates a new `li` element that's used in the suggestion menu. The subsequent call to `.data` associates the actual suggestion item with that new element. `item.autocomplete` is just the "key" for the `.data` call. `.data` is the [instance method on the jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: See, I was looking at these docs:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ vs. http://api.jquery.com/data/

Wow, what a difference.